# How to pass value for DbPropertyEntry?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, ef-code-first

I have created a common method AvoidPropertyModify(T entity, Expression< Func< T, DbPropertyEntry>> properties) in my generic repository to restrict update for entity's specific property. Now, how can i call my method by given exact parameters.

```
public virtual void AvoidPropertyModify(T entity, Expression<Func<T,DbPropertyEntry>> properties)
{
     Entities.Entry(entity).Property(properties).IsModified =false;
}

//Calling 

public JsonResult Update(ChartOfAccounts coa)
{
     AvoidPropertyModify(coa, x =>  new {x.Code,x.Name });  // Giving syntax Error
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>>` expression:

```
public virtual void AvoidPropertyModify<TEntity, TProperty>(
    TEntity entity, 
    Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> getProperty)
    where TEntity : class
{
    var entityEntry = Context.Entry(entity);
    var propertyEntry = entityEntry.Property(getProperty);
    propertyEntry.IsModified = false;
}

public void Update(Customer customer)
{
    AvoidPropertyModify(customer, x => x.Number); 
}
```

Another option to get `propertyEntry` is to pass property name:

```
var propertyEntry = entityEntry.Property("Number");
```

Comment: Thanks @Ilya Chumakov